# Flink - Insufficient number of Network buffers with high parallelism

Tags: apache-flink

I'm getting the error when trying to spin up my pipeline and wonder if there's anyway to resolve this without having to play around with the configurations a lot:

```
java.io.IOException: Insufficient number of network buffers: required 1, but only 0 available. The total number of network buffers is currently set to 32768 of 32768 bytes each. You can increase this number by setting the configuration keys 'taskmanager.network.memory.fraction', 'taskmanager.network.memory.min', and 'taskmanager.network.memory.max'.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.buffer.NetworkBufferPool.createBufferPool(NetworkBufferPool.java:268)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.NetworkEnvironment.setupPartition(NetworkEnvironment.java:212)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.NetworkEnvironment.registerTask(NetworkEnvironment.java:193)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:614)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:749)
```

As suggested by the error, I've tried upping both taskmanager.network.memory.fraction (0.1 -> 0.7) and then upping taskmanager.network.memory.max (1 GB -> 4 GB) which should be more than enough for my current configuration.

My current configuration is:

- 10 instances/task managers
- 25 parallelism/task slots per task manager
- 250 total task slots
- Task manager heap size - 44 GB

Following https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/setup/config.html#configuring-the-network-buffers the calculation should be:

```
#slots-per-TM^2 * #TMs * 4 * 32000 kb/buffer -> 25^2 * 10 * 4 * 32000 = 800 mb roughly
```

Spinning up the pipeline with 200 parallelism works fine with the default max network memory configuration (1 GB max), but running into problems with anything over 210 - I'm having trouble figuring out why 4 GB still isn't enough in this case.

Any tips would be awesome

Thanks

Edit (adding rough sketch of pipeline):

```
        final SingleOutputStreamOperator<MyObject> stream = eventDataStream
            .rebalance() // evenly distribute the IO heavy augmenter work to all available workers.
            // Filter bad events
            .filter(new BadEventFilter())
            .name("BadEventFilter")
            .map(myMapper1)
            .name("myMapper1")
            .disableChaining()
            .flatMap(myFlatMapper)
            .name("myFlatMapper")
            .disableChaining()
            .map(myMapper2)
            .name("myMapper2")
            .startNewChain()
            .keyBy(mySelector)
            //Use the keyed events to create appropriate grouping
            .process(groupingProcessing)
            .name("groupingProcessing")
            .rebalance()
            .flatMap(myGroupingFlatMapper)
            .name("myGroupingFlatMapper")
            .startNewChain()
            .map(myMapper3)
            .name("myMapper3")
            .process(sideArchive)
            .name("sideArchive");
    stream.getSideOutput("myOutputTag")
            .addSink(sink)
            .name("archive");
    stream.addSink(sink)
            .name("sink");
```

Comment: Could you please add your topology? The above recommendation is for each shuffle step and I want to make sure that there not multiple.

Comment: @arvid I'm not too sure what you mean by topology, but I've added my main execution steps hoping that's what you mean

Comment: Could you please add why you disabled chaining?

Comment: My original intention was to see if there was a potential bottle neck at one of the mappers, so I separated them out, but they're definitely not needed anymore

Comment: Btw are you really running on Flink 1.3 is the link coincidentally for 1.3? If you are indeed using 1.3, is there a reason to not use a supported version? (1.10+)

Comment: Sorry I confused you, we're using 1.15 - just coincidentally 1.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you have too many shuffles and therefore require a lot of network memory buffers.

The formula

```
#slots-per-TM^2 * #TMs * 4
```

is for one shuffle step, and you have if I'm not mistaken 7 or 8 (2 rebalances, 2 new chain starts, 2 chains disabling, 2 sinks). In this case even the rough estimate is `25^2 * 10 * 4 * 8 = 200,000` network buffers and in your case you have a bit more then `32,000`.

The reason why the simple increase to `4Gb` does not help can be that the `4Gb` max memory limit is not reached - the real amount is calculated as `taskmanager.network.memory.fraction` of flink managed memory.

To be honest, I don't see any reason for disabling chaining and starting new chains - this just introduces a lot more shuffling, so instead of tweaking network settings I would suggest getting rid of new chain creation and simplifying a bit the pipeline:

```java
        final SingleOutputStreamOperator<MyObject> stream = eventDataStream
            // Filter bad events
            // filter before rebalance to reduce the network traffic.
            .filter(new BadEventFilter())
            .name("BadEventFilter")
            .rebalance() // evenly distribute the IO heavy augmenter work to all available workers.
            .map(myMapper1)
            .name("myMapper1")
            //.disableChaining()
            .flatMap(myFlatMapper)
            .name("myFlatMapper")
            //.disableChaining()
            .map(myMapper2)
            .name("myMapper2")
            //.startNewChain()
            .keyBy(mySelector)
            //Use the keyed events to create appropriate grouping
            .process(groupingProcessing)
            .name("groupingProcessing")
            //.rebalance()
            .flatMap(myGroupingFlatMapper)
            .name("myGroupingFlatMapper")
            //.startNewChain()
            .map(myMapper3)
            .name("myMapper3")
            .process(sideArchive)
            .name("sideArchive");
    stream.getSideOutput("myOutputTag")
            .addSink(sink)
            .name("archive");
    stream.addSink(sink)
            .name("sink");
```

Comment: I was going to write something similar (real life caught up). In general, try to reduce the number of shuffles as much as possible. Also double-check if your rebalance in the beginning is necessary (e.g., perform comparison benchmarks).

Comment: Thanks for your insight Mikalai - I'll try out the suggested approach. Do you also mind explaining why the 4GB isn't reached? Since my settings for taskmanager.memory.flink.size/taskmanager.heap.mb = 44 GB -> this means that if the fraction is set to 0.1, it will default to 4 GB max right?

Comment: could you please specify what flink version you use? the memory model changed in 1.10 compared to 1.9

Comment: We use Flink 1.15, but I believe the old configurations map over to the new configurations according to: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/memory/mem_migration.html

Comment: I might be wrong, but it seems that the latest stable version is 1.11 so not sure whether 1.15 is a valid version

Comment: Btw for 200 buffers of 32 kb each, you need 6.4 GB RAM and not just the 4 GB that you aimed for. However, only have of them are really needed (3.2 GB) for exclusive buffers. That's why it might have worked with parallelism of 200. However, the recommendation would be to go much higher.